# When you are going to show your respect and tell somebody that meeting with them has been an honor for you

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Imagine you as a representative of a popular party are going to talk to your country's vice president and as a sign of your respect towards him, you want to express your feelings. I was wondering if someone could let me know which one of the following choices work better in my self-made example:

> -...................to have this opportunity to hold this discussion with you.
>
> **a)** It was a great honor for me
>
> **b)** It was a big source of pride for me

For me, they both work here properly though the first one seems to be more common. I guess one can exchange them together without any specific change in meaning.

If you confirm my taking, then please let me knew if they both sound natural in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only choice that would make sense is

> It was a great honor for me to have this opportunity to meet and discuss *something* with you.

Saying it was an honor compliments the recipient, saying it was a great source of pride compliments you.